# Oracle WebCenter Content Presenter Template

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, contentpresenter, webcenter

I need to create a content presenter template and integrate it into webcenter. But I am new in this technology. Can anyone give any reference from where I can learn these stuff, any step-by-step tutorial. Any information will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the resources Peter provided, [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/portal/learnmore/wcportal-onlinetraining-444652.html) will help you as well:

**Creating and Using Page Templates in Oracle WebCenter Portal Applications** - In a WebCenter Portal application, page templates provide a means for creating the application’s pages with a common look. Each page of an application is stamped out from a page template, which provides common elements for the page. The individual pages can add their specific content, extending the page template. In this training module, you learn how to create and use page templates in both WebCenter Portal applications and in WebCenter Portal: Spaces.

[Recorded Presentation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/webcenter/wcp-pagetemplates.swf) 50 minutes, 49.3 MB

Presentation slides (PDF) -- you'll have to visit the page above to find

Related Documents -- you'll have to visit the page above to find as I cannot post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of links to the documentation. The best ones are the [Users Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/webcenter.1111/e10149/toc.htm) and the [Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/webcenter.1111/e10148/toc.htm).

- [Publishing Content Using Content Presenter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/webcenter.1111/e10149/content_cp.htm#BABBDDFB)
- [Creating Content Presenter Display Templates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/webcenter.1111/e10148/jpsdg_content_presenter.htm#CCHDAHGB)